# Equations in groups

Tags: group-theory

I want to solve an equation
$$f(\sigma , \tau , \delta)=1$$
where  $\sigma,\tau,\delta$ are elements from a given group $G$, and $1 \in G$ is the unit element.

When I say solve I mean give sufficient **and necessery** conditions on elements $\sigma,\tau,\delta$ (e.g. by commutators) for the equation to hold.

To illustrate what I want, I will start with an easy exmaple. Take the equation:
$$\sigma \tau \delta = \sigma \delta \tau$$
The sufficient and necessery condition is $[\tau,\delta]=1$

Now my equation is:
$$\sigma \tau \delta = \delta \tau \sigma$$
Obviously, $[\delta,\tau]=[\sigma,\delta\tau]=1$ are sufficient conditions .My question is, are they necessery? It seems to me that not, and if it is indeed the case -  is it possible to give sufficient and necessery conditions, and if it is - what are they?

Comment: Another condition might be $\tau = \sigma^{-1}$ or similar. Another is that every element in the group squares to the identity. I don't think this is well-posed in general.

Comment: May be we should use conjugation for proof?

Comment: The condition $\tau=\sigma^{-1}$ is not necessery, as any commutative group shows. The other one $\sigma^2=1$ is not general enough as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition involving commutators is $[\tau\delta,\tau\sigma]=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $w(x,y,z)$ is a freely reduced word then $w_b(x,y,z)=(w(x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1})^{-1}$ reads the word backwards. The condition $\sigma \tau \delta = \delta \tau \sigma$ then is saying that this operation is the identity for it. This is a necessary and sufficient condition for your equation. Note that the words $w(x,y,z)$ and $w_b(x,y,z)$ are *trace equivalent*, i.e., for every representation $α : F → SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ we have $tr(α(w)) = tr(α(w_b))$.